# How to assign a variable to each coordinate of black spots?

Tags: python

I want to get my mouse to move to each black dot in a certain photo using pynput and at the moment I have a program that finds the coordinate of each black spot, but it stores all of them in one variable. How would I assign each coordinate to a different variable? My code is below.

```
# read input
img = cv2.imread("dots.png")

low = (0,0,0)
high = (0,0,0)

mask = cv2.inRange(img, low, high)
mask = 255 - mask

# find black coordinates
coords = np.argwhere(mask==0)
for p in coords:
    pt = (p[0],p[1])
    print(pt)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('dots.png', mask)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the output

```
(30, 110)
(31, 109)
(31, 110)
(46, 505)
(46, 506)
(47, 505)
(47, 506)
(254, 78)
(254, 79)
(255, 78)
(255, 79)
(268, 477)
(268, 478)
(269, 477)
(269, 478)
(270, 477)
(270, 478)
```

Comment: would a list of dictionary work for you? or a list of tuples (which it seems you already have). Why do you need them in multiple "variables"?

Comment: If you're using pyautogui couldn't you just put this in your `for` loop: `pyautogui.moveTo(p[0], p[1])`

Comment: @TenaciousB yeah, a dictionary list would work for me

Comment: @TenaciousB i tried putting pyautogui.moveTo(p[0], p[1])  in my for loop but the mouse only goes to the first cooardinates.

Comment: does a dictionary like this work for you: `{'point0': (1, 5), 'point1': (3, 4), 'point2': (257, 15), 'point3': (159, 4)}`

Comment: @TenaciousB im not sure where to put that in my code.

Comment: @TenaciousB nevermind, your suggestion worked, if you put it as an answer I will accept it, thank you!

Comment: already answered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will convert the list of coords to a dict with names as the keys, not sure if it will actually help you access each point easier because they are already "variables" as list items. This makes each point a key-value pair which is kind of like a named variable:

```py
coords = [
    (30, 110),
    (31, 109),
    (31, 110),
    (46, 505),
    (46, 506),
    (47, 505),
    (47, 506),
    (254, 78),
    (254, 79),
    (255, 78),
    (255, 79),
    (268, 477),
    (268, 478),
    (269, 477),
    (269, 478),
    (270, 477),
    (270, 478),
]

points = {f'point{coords.index(pt)}': (pt[0], pt[1])
          for pt in coords}

print(points)
```

Output:

```
{'point0': (30, 110), 'point1': (31, 109), 'point2': (31, 110), 'point3': (46, 505), 'point4': (46, 506), 'point5': (47, 505), 'point6': (47, 506), 'point7': (254, 78), 'point8': (254, 79), 'point9': (255, 78), 'point10': (255, 79), 'point11': (268, 477), 'point12': (268, 478), 'point13': (269, 477), 'point14': (269, 478), 'point15': (270, 477), 'point16': (270, 478)}
```

Another option could be to use a generator and pop the points off that as in order as you need them